# Sum of Combination series having N constant and subscript is multiple of K

Tags: combinatorics

So here is my question. Its not an programming question but mathematical. I want to know that is there any direct formula for this type of serires written as: nCk + nC2*k + nC3*k + ... nCa*k

Comment: There seems to be some kind of a pattern brewing on wolfram in terms of trigonometric functions for $k=1,2,3,4,5$ for $$\sum_{c=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor} {n \choose c\cdot k}$$

Comment: This is not going to work for me. Calculating this isnt a feasible solution.